# google billing queryPurchasesAsync & queryProductDetailsAsync doesn't return any result

Tags: android

In my project I am trying to integrate new version (5.0) of google billing lib, I am following the google example

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/play-billing-codelab#3

as an example there are two functions:

```
fun queryPurchases() {
   if (!billingClient.isReady) {
       Log.e(TAG, "queryPurchases: BillingClient is not ready")
   }
   // Query for existing subscription products that have been purchased.
   billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(
       QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder().setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS).build()
   ) { billingResult, purchaseList ->
       if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
           if (!purchaseList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
               _purchases.value = purchaseList
           } else {
               _purchases.value = emptyList()
           }

       } else {
           Log.e(TAG, billingResult.debugMessage)
       }
   }
}
```

which should return `purchases that the user has previously made` and another function is

```
fun queryProductDetails() {
   val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
   val productList = mutableListOf<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product>()
   for (product in LIST_OF_PRODUCTS) {

       productList.add(
           QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
               .setProductId(product)
               .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
               .build()
       )

       params.setProductList(productList).let { productDetailsParams ->
           Log.i(TAG, "queryProductDetailsAsync")
           billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(productDetailsParams.build(), this)
       }
   }
}
```

where as a result I expect to get `available products`, however, those two functions return empty lists as a result.

I know that these products exist as before the new lib version I used the previous one `4.x.x` and it worked.

What am I missing here? Any advice appreciates.

Comment: Have you figured this out by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, eventually in my case it was a configuration issues, I was need to do a few changes (just for debug, this shouldn't be in production)

1)

```
...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
...
```

2. delete this line (if you have)

```
...
applicationIdSuffix '.feature'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I just migrated to V5 and it's working for me.

For `queryPurchasesAsync` are you sure you have subscription products? You're passing in `BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS` as product type? Maybe this should be `BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP`. The code looks ok otherwise.

For `queryProductDetailsAsync` you're calling it in the loop multiple times instead of calling it once your `productList` is populated. Also the `let` is unnecessary, there's no reason to create a new scope. Using `map` you can simplify the code to:

```
val products = inAppPurchaseProductIds.map { productId ->
   QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
      .setProductId(productId)
      .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
      .build()
}

val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(products).build()
billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params, this)
```

Note I used `BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP`. If you have subscriptions, you'd need to change that to `BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS`.

Comment: Thanks! Your code looks pretty self-explained, however, why do you think `fold()` is a better option here? Why don't use just `map()`?

Comment: @Sirop4ik you're right, map is better in this case. I changed my answer to use map instead of fold.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the ID of your Productlist, is your subscription Product ID, not plan ID.  The product ID contains "_", and plan ID contains "-". DON'T click and open 'View subscription' page and copy plan ID inside.